# Android SimpleOnGestureListener trying to detect the finger off motion

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

hi I have a button which when (pressed) clicked will fire off another activity. I also have a SimpleOnGestureListener listening for a slide across the button which when detected will invoke another button on the screen.

The original problem I had is when the user stopped sliding their finger the onClick of the button will fire off (by detecting an onclick). I put a boolean check in place, so when slide is detected I set this to false, which onclick checks against. I then reset this boolean at the end of the onclick process. 
this means in short...

```
press finger
detect slide
set onClick to Disable
Slide finish
Finger Off
Onclick triggered
ignore all code, and set onclick to Enable.
```

Now the problem I have is that onclick doesn't always fire off, so sometimes there is a problem with false still being set as the slide is being picked up but the onclick isnt'

can I detect a finger off at the end of a slide or indeed the end of a slide so I can reset my boolean?

I have seen things like ACTION_UP but have no idea how to use that to set my boolean variable?

Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a method to detect touch like **onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)** in that check for the action which triggered the event like this..

```
  if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        yourbool = false;
     }
```

Comment: ah awesome. can't wait to try this :)

Comment: hi, I'm just trying it now, having trouble where I can put this if statement. I have a  "class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener { etc..." and under here I see options for a ondown, onscroll etc.. have tried this if statement in onscroll but it doesn't pick it up?

Comment: alright I found it, sorry was looking in the wrong place. great works a treat :)